# Error with ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have been working with ECSlidingViewController for a while and never had this problem before. I am getting the following error on swiping the view to see the Menu. Anyone faced this problem before?

**[UIImage imageWithUIView:]: unrecognized selector sent to class**

I have all my dependencies in a Podfile.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you calling `imageWithUIView:` at any time? Ensure the files added to the project include the category on `UIImage`.

Comment: @Viruss: please use boldface and other formatting sparingly.

Comment: @Wain.. Please look at the edit. I have those files you are talking about.

Comment: @Wain.. I am not calling imageWithUIView directly from my code. I am calling [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight]; which is calling that method indirectly.

Comment: Try upgrading ECSlidingViewController. That category has been removed recently.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that category `UIImage+ImageWithUIView` is added to your target.

---

In response to Ruchira's comment:

Unless I'm missing something, I believe that above **may** answer the question. The problem described by author of this question concern missing `imageWithUIView` method - `ECSlidinViewController` uses this internally.

Obviously, the problem comes from method not being available during the runtime - this indicates that method was not linked during the compilation process, so there is high chance that this category is not properly added to current target (and is not being compiled at all).

Comment: could you please elaborate on this please. I am using Cocoa pods to manage my dependencies. I am not sure what you meant when you said, Make sure that category UIImage+ImageWithUIView is added to your target. There is a separate project for Pods itself and I looked at the target and linked binaries and everything seems okay, Let me take some screen shots and edit my question for better understanding.